# iOS Swift max(), min()

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, I am trying to use the max() and min() functions.

```
max<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
min<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
```

I am trying to use the max() function in this way:

```
var paddleX: Int = Int(paddle.position.x) + Int(location.x - previousLocation.x)
max(paddleX, paddle.frame.x/2, nil)
```

but I am getting this error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type of '()' to type 'NilType'

Is the `nil` causing this problem? What is `rest: T...` supposed to be?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't pass anything at all there. It's a variadic function, you can call it with two or more parameters.

Comment: so you can just do `max(paddleX, paddle.frame.x/2)`

Comment: :-) Interesting that two or more parameters are allowed to `max` and `min` when they could allow 1 or more :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the empty parameters for simple comparable data types, if you have a more complex data structures you need to provide a closure. Note: the order of the comparison are the following for both `max` and `min` if you do it backward you get wrong results.

```
[(0, "a"), (2, "b"), (5, "f"), (6, "g")].min(by: {$0.0 < $1.0}) // min (0, "a")
[(0, "a"), (2, "b"), (5, "f"), (6, "g")].max(by: {$0.0 < $1.0}) // max (6, "g")
```